# How to Load a local .JSON file in .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Issue
Unable to load local JSON file in a javascript file which is spun up with node.

## Details

The question is straight forward but I am not serving the javascript file in a browser. I have a javascript file which has the logic, I then spin it up with:

```
node main.js
```

I googled a few solutions, they recommend using JQuery or XMLHttpRequest but they appear to be running into issues related to the fact i am no serving this in a browser.

## Project Background

I am using a raspberry PI to get data from an IR Temperature Sensor. I am using python to get calculate the voltage, convert to celsius, then export that as a JSON file. I then plan to load this file into my javascript file which then configures angular fire Database and pushes this data.

I have a front-end application that will then pull this down and display the end data to the user.

If I go with the JQuery:

## Option 1

### sample:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
});
```

#### Error

```
$.getJSON is not a function even though I am requiring jQuery.
```

## Option 2

If I go with pure javascript, I see

### sample

```
 function loadJSON(callback) {   

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'my_data.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }
```

#### Error

```
xobj.overrideMimeType is not a function
```

## TL/DR

How do I load a local JSON file into a javascript file that is not loaded into a browser but instead spun up with node,

```
node main.js
```

Comment: `const jsonData = require('./test.json');`

Comment: what?!! I spent hours looking for this single line of code. *facepalm. Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js can load JSON files through `require`. See the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

- If filename begins with `'./' or '/' or '../'`

  - If filename.json is a file, parse filename.json to a JavaScript Object.  STOP

Most likely what you want is `const json = require('./test.json')` assuming `test.json` is in the same directory as the code requiring it. Remember that `require` *parses* the JSON, so `json` in the example is a JavaScript Object.

Comment: A little footnote to your declaration: Naming the const as json will result in an error, since json is already declared (namely the main JSON-Module).